# How should I map a function onto a string array in java?

Tags: java, trim

I want to split a string and trim each word in the newly established array. Is there a simple (functional) way in Java how to do it as a one liner without the use of a cycle?

```
String[] stringarray = inputstring.split(";");
for (int i = 0; i < stringarray.length; i++) { 
    stringarray[i] = stringarray[i].trim(); 
}
```

EDIT: corrected the cycle (Andreas' comment)

Comment: Maybe `inputstring.split("\\s*;\\s*")` and you're done?

Comment: @ernest_k What if there is space at start and/or end of `inputstring` like `" ab;cd "`?

Comment: @Pshemo Call `trim()` on `inputstring` before splitting it.

Comment: *FYI:* Strings are *immutable*, so that code should have been `for (int i = 0; i < stringarray.length; i++) { stringarray[i] = stringarray[i].trim(); }`

Comment: @ernest_k yes, this does not work for all the cases as Pshelmo says

Comment: @krenkz call `trim()` before `split()`, as Andreas mentions. That will solve it.

Comment: that is what I was originally doing, but did not work for some cases either, Arvind' s version seems to be ok

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in the following way:

```
String[] stringarray = inputstring.trim().split("\\s*;\\s*");
```

**Explanation of the regex:**

1. `\s*` is zero or more times whitespace
2. `\s*;\s*` specifies zero or more times whitespace followed by `;` which may be followed by zero or more times whitespace

Answer (score 3):

With streams you could do this:

```
String[] stringarray = Arrays.stream(inputstring.split(";"))
        .map(String::trim)
        .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Answer (score 2):

This may not be pure Array solution but a java 8 solution:

```
String str = " string1 ;string2 ;string3 ;string4;";
String [] s = Arrays.stream(str.split(";")).map(String::trim).collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(new String[]{});
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s));
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, I know about the Collectors option, but it looks like an overkill for such a simple thing

Answer (score 1):

First convert the array to a stream (using the Arrays class), then use the map function, then convert back to array.

https://mkyong.com/java8/java-8-how-to-convert-a-stream-to-array/